# Script working in major browsers but not IE8

Tags: html, internet-explorer

I hace some code that adds dynamic input boxes on a click. In all of the major browsers, it works fine. But in IE8 it does nothing. There are no errors being reported and developer tools shows no errors either. should this code work with IE8. Thanks

jQuery 1.7.1

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
```

Script an doctype in the head section.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

var MaxInputs       = 7; //maximum input boxes allowed
var InputsWrapper   = $("#INTKInputsWrapper"); //Input boxes wrapper ID
var AddButton       = $("#INTKAddMoreFileBox"); //Add button ID

var x = InputsWrapper.length; //initlal text box count
var FieldCount=1; //to keep track of text box added

$(AddButton).click(function (e)  //on add input button click
{
        if(x <= MaxInputs) //max input box allowed
        {
            FieldCount++; //text box added increment
            //add input box
            $(InputsWrapper).append('<div><input type="text" name="box_add[]'+FieldCount+'" required="required" " /><a href="#" class="removeclass"><img src="/domain/users/css/images/redclose.png" style="margin-left: 10px; margin-right:10px;" /></a><span style="margin-left:2px;font-size:10px;color: grey;">Remove</span></div>');
            x++; //text box increment
        }
return false;
});

$("body").on("click",".removeclass", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        if( x > 1 ) {
                $(this).parent('div').remove(); //remove text box
                x--; //decrement textbox
        }
return false;
}) 

});
</script>
```

HTML relevant code

```
       <fieldset>
       <legend>Input box reference(s)</legend>
       <a href="javascript:void(0)" id="INTKAddMoreFileBox" class="btn btn-info">Add More Boxes</a><span style="margin-left:10px;font-size:10px;color: grey;">( Maximum 8 )</span>

<div id="INTKInputsWrapper">

       <input name="box_add[]" type="text" required="required />
       <a href="#" class="removeclass"></a><a style="margin-left: 14px;" href="javascript:void(0)" class="boxhelp">Help</a>

</div>
       </fieldset>
```

Comment: $(AddButton).click(function... <-- you're using jQuery's "ON" for events elsewhere. Why not here?

Comment: Why are you using "return false" when the caller is not expecting a return value?

Comment: Create a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) of the problem if you can

Comment: @diodeus Not sure. I found this on the net. What modifications would you suggest. Thanks